# JFileChooser causes the application into Busy/Not responding state

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am using `JFileChooser` to browse and load a file.
File chooser is loading properly and /i was able to select the file and load as well.
The issue is soon after opening the `JFilechooser`, the background window of the application goes in to  Busy/Not Responding state. And if I Drag the
file chooser window, the background is not drawing properly. It causes the application into the crash state. Any idea why it happens.
Please find my below code

```
LoadFileButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setFileFilter(filterWithoutExtension);
            chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            File selectedFile = null;
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                //Do My Stuff
            }
        }
    });
```

Please find my FileFilter

```
FileFilter filterWithoutExtension = new FileFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        return !f.getName().contains(".");
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "My Description";
    }
};
```

Comment: Doesn't SWT have its **own** file chooser component?

Comment: Yes It has.but i want to select  and load files with out extensions.Using FileFialog i was not able to create a new FileFilter and use it.Thats why i used JFileChoser

Comment: I'd guess that is why the app. locks up. Swing & SWT do not play well together, don't mix them.

Comment: I think if you call `chooser.showOpenDialog(null);` in `EDT` with help of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...);`, it helps you, but in that case you Dialog will not be a modal. Also don't mix Swing/SWT.